# How too add background image to root on Tornado fx

Tags: css, kotlin, tornadofx

i'm learning about `kotlin+TornadoFX` combo.

Actually i have a problem while designing my UI, my goal is to set a `background image` on my windows.

```
class StyleSheet : Stylesheet() {

    init {

        root {
             backgroundImage += URI("/background.jpg")//Uri recognized but img is not loaded
    //        backgroundColor +=Color.BLANCHEDALMOND //this still work
        }

        textArea {
            content {
                backgroundColor += Color.LIGHTGREY
            }
        }
        listView {
            backgroundColor += Color.TRANSPARENT
        }
    }


}
```

i've checked from my IDE `background.jpg` position 
(from copy Path from repository of intellij) background.jpg
I have already a resource folder ( jvmMain/kotlin/resources) and the editor recognize bg uri as correct (ex. if i move the jpg in another folder, intellij update the uri), i dont have any error/warning segnation on loadin, but i've the classic gray bg yet

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it and it seems to work. But it seems to be a picky process. The most important thing seems that your image needs to be set to your resources folder. I haven't been able to make it work any other way. If your image is directly inside the your resources folder, then `URI("/background.jpg")` should work. If it's in a subdirectory within the resources folder, let's say 'images', then `URI("/images/background.jpg")` should work.

Comment: I have already a resource folder ( jvmMain/kotlin/resources) and the editor recognize bg uri as correct (ex. if i move the jpg in another folder, intellij update the uri), i dont have any error/warning segnation on loadin, but i've the classic gray bg yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like that:

```java
     style {
            backgroundImage += File("src/jvmMain/resources/background.jpg").toURI()
        }
```